# В путь добавляется двойной слеш после редиректа Nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx

Конфиг Nginx

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name admin.sitedomain.online www.admin.sitedomain.online;

    access_log /var/log/admin_sitedomain_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/admin_sitedomain_error.log;


    location / {
        return 301 https:/admin.sitedomain.online/$request_uri;
    }
}

server{
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name admin.sitedomain.online;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.sitedomain.online/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.sitedomain.online/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.sitedomain.online/chain.pem;

    access_log /var/log/admin_sitedomain_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/admin_sitedomain_error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend.sitedomain.host:5300;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

При переходе по http://admin.sitedomain.online происходит редирект на https://admin.sitedomain.online//, что ломает фронт, чего не хватает в nginx конфиге?

Фронт - React, может это важно.

**UPD.** Помогло удаление / в роуте редиректа 80->443

Comment: `.online/$request_uri` — вот здесь лишний слеш уберите

Comment: @andreymal может магия, а может и нет, у меня 2 одинаковых в логике конфига, для "админки" и для основного фронта. Изменил согласно вашему комментарию в обоих конфигах, но для sitedomain.online все равно при редиректе остался лишний слеш.
`location / {
        return 301 https://sitedomain.online$request_uri;
    }`
service nginx reload -> service nginx restart сделал, тест проводил в браузере в режиме инкогнито

Comment: Почистьте кэш браузера

Comment: Спасибо! На "чистом" браузере все корректно.